# How to decrypt javascript code extracted from PDF

Tags: encryption, javascript

I analyzed PDF, and extract javascript code.

But javascript code is encrypted.

I can't decrypt it.

Please advise me.

javascript code

```
\040\040\040\040\146\165\156\143\164\151\157\156\043\164\151\157\156\040\163\167\050\051...
```

Comment: It’s not encrypted, it’s just encoded (octal escape sequences). Just open up a JavaScript interpreter like the console built-in in most browsers, put the code in quotes like `"\040\040\040\040\146\165\156\143\164\151\157\156\043\164\151\157\156\040\163\167\050\051…"` and you’ll get `"    function#tion sw()…"` as result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question seems off-topic to me, as embedded JavaScript in PDF documents has nothing to do with security. That being said, perhaps you can give [this tutorial](http://mariomalwareanalysis.blogspot.be/2012/03/decode-pdf-and-extract-javascript.html) a try.